# Necesito obtener el valor de un select, que esta dentro de un ciclo, y se repite el nombre e ID

Tags: javascript, html

El select esta dentro de un modal, y se genera con un ciclo, y necesito en la funcion saber el valor especifico de ese select

```
 <select id="lote" name="lote" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <? while ($registro3=@mysql_fetch_array($rs3) ) {?> 
                  <option value="<? echo $registro3['ID']; ?>" name="<? echo $registro3['ID']; ?>"><? echo $registro3['NOMBRE']; ?></option>


          <? }?>
   </select>

Este este es el codigo completo del modal:

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<? echo $registro0['ID']; ?>" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">CREAR NUEVO REPORTE DE CAMPO</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <? include('dbconecta.php');     @mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
      $cadbusca3="select  * FROM MA_LOTES where ID_PRODUCTOR='".$registro0['ID']."' ";
      $_SESSION['cadbusca_MODAL2']=$cadbusca3;
  $rs3 = @mysql_query($cadbusca3);
  $rows3 = @mysql_num_rows($rs3);?>


      <font>SELECCIONE EL LOTE</font>
      <select id="lote" name="lote" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <? while ($registro3=@mysql_fetch_array($rs3) ) {?> 
                  <option value="<? echo $registro3['ID']; ?>" name="<? echo $registro3['ID']; ?>"><? echo $registro3['NOMBRE']; ?></option>


          <? }?>
   </select>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step" onclick="$productor(<? echo $registro0['ID']; ?>);"  data-dismiss="modal">GUARDAR</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $("select").eq(0); $("select").eq(1) //Puedes seleccionarlo por Index

Comment: Como que por index?

Comment: De que funcion estas hablando?  Porque tienes `$productor` en `onclick`?  Es una funcion en PHP o en javascript?

Comment: Es en javascript, en el Onclick, ejecuta la funcion y dentro de la funcion pogo la variable de session para que me de el id en arguments[0], de la sigueinte manera:
onclick="$productor(<? echo $registro0['ID']; ?>);"

Comment: Dentro de la siguiente instruccion puedo concatenar el arguments en la parte del ID??
var lote=document.getElementById("lote").value;
Y que quedara algo asi:
var lote=document.getElementById("lote"arguments[0]).value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira aqui te dejo un ejemplo, modifique un poco el tuyo para probarlo

```
<select id="lote" name="lote">
    <? for($x=0;$x<=10;$x++){ ?> 
        <option value="<?=$x?>" name="<?=$x?>"><?=$x?></option>
    <? } ?>
</select>
<select id="lote" name="lote">
    <? for($x=0;$x<=10;$x++){ ?> 
        <option value="<?=$x?>" name="<?=$x?>"><?=$x?></option>
    <? } ?>
</select>

<script>
    $("select").change(function(){
        alert($("select").eq(0).val());
        alert($("select").eq(1).val());
    });
</script>
```

Lo que hago es utilizar `.eq()` para hubicarlos dentro del DOM
Mas info https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Los objetos dentro del DOM pueden ser seleccionador por orden de definición (index)
Mas info https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Pense una solucion mas adecuada y facil, poniendo el ID del modal en el arguments de la funcion; Como puedo concatenar el get element, con el arguments??
Pera que se concatene : "lote"arguments[0];
var lote=document.getElementById("lote").value;

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta aqui:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step" onclick="$productor(<? echo $registro0['ID']; ?>);"  data-dismiss="modal">GUARDAR</button>
```

Estas pasando como parametro el ultimo valor que tiene `$registro3`.  La solucion es agarrar el valor seleccionado en jQuery.  Algo asi:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step" onclick="$productor($('#lote').val());"  data-dismiss="modal">GUARDAR</button>
```

Comment: Intento pintarlo de la siguiente manera:
console.log(arguments[1]);
Y me dice undefined.